# Does Doxygen support C++/CX syntax?

Tags: visual-studio, doxygen, c++-cx

Doxygen seems confused by some [C++/CX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh699871%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) syntax constructs (the new C++ extensions introduced by Microsoft for Windows 8 development). Is this a known issue? Are there patches to make it work? Or a better doc system to use? (Bear in mind that the code base in question also runs on non-Microsoft platforms.)

Comment: Doxygen does have support for C++/CLI.  Since C++/CLI and C++/CX are largely the same, enabling C++/CLI support in Doxygen may help.  (Note also that Doxygen does not support many C++11 features very well, though, e.g. it has some difficulty with trailing return types in places.  I expect this will be rectified in future updates.)

Answer (score 1):

Doxygen supports C++/CLI.  The C++/CX syntax for declarations is (nearly?) identical to the C++/CLI syntax, so enabling C++/CLI support in the Doxygen options should work fine.